# How to create a UEFI kernel in NASM on Linux

Tags: x86, kernel, qemu, osdev, uefi

I have been following this guide for OS development [OS Development on Windows](https://hackerpulp.com/os/os-development-windows-1-building-uefi-applications-nasm/)

However, I do not like the windows development environment, and so I am trying to transfer these instructions over to my preferred Linux environment.

I have tried the tutorial from [Rod's Books](https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-programming/hello.html), and everything compiles correctly, and I receive the hello.efi file... but how do I boot from it? I use the command `qemu-system-x86_64 -bios OVMF.fd -kernel hello.efi -net none`, but I just get the typical EFI shell.

What I would really like is to have a Linux version of the Hacker Pulp guide.

I have also tried this guide from [kalzlauskas](https://kazlauskas.me/entries/x64-uefi-os-1.html), and this instructions from the osdev [UEFI Bare Bones](https://wiki.osdev.org/UEFI_Bare_Bones).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The main problem is that you can't run an *EFI* application directly with QEMU's `-kernel` option. `-kernel` is meant for starting Multiboot compliant executables or loading Linux bzImage files.

---

Since your question suggests you have managed to compile and link an *EFI* application with one of the tutorials, this answer will strictly focus on methods of running it with QEMU. Which tutorial or method you followed to build the *EFI* application itself doesn't matter.

Use this command in your project directory to create a series of subdirectories for use as an *EFI* boot drive:

```
mkdir -p bootdrv/EFI/BOOT/
```

You only have to create the directories once. Once they have been created, copy your `hello.efi` file to the file named `bootdrv/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI`. `EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` is the default boot file for 64-bit *UEFI*. On 32-bit *UEFI* the default boot file is `EFI/BOOT/BOOTIA32.EFI`. Run the following command to launch your *EFI* program:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -bios OVMF.fd -net none -drive file=fat:rw:bootdrv,format=raw
```

This mounts the `bootdrv` directory as a FAT file system in the emulator as the first hard drive. 64-bit *EFI* should automatically run the file `EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI`

---

As an alternative you can copy your `hello.efi` file to the directory `bootdrv/EFI/BOOT/`, and create a startup script with the name `bootdrv/EFI/BOOT/startup.nsh` containing the following commands:

```
\EFI\BOOT\hello.efi
pause
```

`EFI/BOOT/startup.nsh` is the default startup script that will be run in the absence of a default *EFI* application. The file should contain a blank line after the last command. The command `\EFI\BOOT\hello.efi` runs `hello.efi` and `pause` prompts to press a key. You don't have to specify `pause`, it's just convenient if the program you run exits back to the shell. You can run it with same command as before:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -bios OVMF.fd -net none -drive file=fat:rw:bootdrv,format=raw
```

This mounts the `bootdrv` directory as a FAT file system in the emulator as the first hard drive. *EFI* will load `EFI/BOOT/startup.nsh` as a startup script and execute the commands contained in it. That should automatically run `hello.efi`.

Comment: Is this for the "Rod's Books" tutorial?

Comment: @JonathanDewein : It doesn't depend on a particular tutorial. Since you said you were able to build an EFI application called `hello.efi` I focused on your real problem of running it. Once you have your EFI file built (no matter how you built it or what tutorial) - the method above wold allow you to run it on Linux. You can't use the QEMU `-kernel` option to directly run an EFI application.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, so much, for your help. I was confused at first because I was led to a "boot manager" of sorts. Once I booted into the EFI Shell and ran 'fs0:', 'hello.efi', it ran my EFI hello world application.

Next step...kernel development with UEFI. Do you happen to have any suggestions? I am reading the specs and some interesting white papers at uefi.org currently.

Comment: @JonathanDewein I have no real recommendations regarding actual tutorials for OS development using EFI. Probably finding existing code on Github that does it would be a starting point.